# Calculation for conversion of Lat/Lon to World Geographic Reference System (GEOREF)

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, proj

Does any one have a reference to, or the actual code, to convert Lat / Lons to Georef code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georef)?  I am also interested in finding a conversion from lat/lon to MGRS.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide some more context, such as what format your coordinates are in, or what environment you're working in?

Comment: Scratch my last comment. This question is not really a question about projections -- more about parsing or format conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is source code for MGRS and GEOREF in the NGA [MSP GEOTRANS 3.3 software](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/geotrans/index.html).

A good explanation of GEOREF is available on its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georef). It's a relatively straightforward format.

MGRS is more complicated. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system) has a good explanation including some of the things you have to watch out for and links. To support MGRS, you have implement transverse Mercator as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx

This link even gives you the GEOREF using lat/lon

Comment: As far as I can tell, this link doesn't provide an algorithm for converting lat/lon (WGS84) to Georef; it just gives an overview and an interface for converting points one at a time. Batch conversions require a paid subscription.